# Why my SD card name is not the same as I format it?

Tags: sd-card, storage, android-10

I formatted my SD card into 2 partition. The first one is `exfat` and the second partition is `f2fs`.
I renamed the first partition as "Limbo" and the second as "Saint".

On Linux it shows both name but on the android is different, the first partition is "Limbo" and The second partition is "SanDisk SD Card".

Is there's any reason why it is not the same?

Using Gnome disk:

[image]

Comment: Is it partition label or filesystem label? Partition table MBR or GPT? What tools you used on Linux and Android to show the label?

Comment: @Irfan I think it's partition label, updated post. Sorry for late reply

Comment: Getting the partition label seems to be not that easy on Android, therefore a lot of apps show the volume serial name or a name generated using the card manufacturer instead. Check if the partition labels are shown correctly in [DiskInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo). This app usually shows the real partition names (as "partition nickname").